# echo in controller

Tags: controllers, ce-1.9.2.2

Is there a way to don't generate the layout, but write our something with echo?
(Like a blank page with some text on it)

Or is there a way to get magento to not send any headers?

I have this because I would load this controller with ajax:

```
$this->getResponse()->clearAllHeaders();
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*");
```

If I just simple echo some text, then I will get the following error:

```
2016-01-21T11:56:10+00:00 DEBUG (7): HEADERS ALREADY SENT:
[0] /www/htdocs/w0114ce0/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:52
[1] /www/htdocs/w0114ce0/www/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php:773
[2] /www/htdocs/w0114ce0/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:84
[3] /www/htdocs/w0114ce0/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php:184
[4] /www/htdocs/w0114ce0/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:365
[5] /www/htdocs/w0114ce0/www/app/Mage.php:684
[6] /www/htdocs/w0114ce0/www/index.php:83

2016-01-21T12:08:03+00:00 DEBUG (7): Cannot send headers; headers already sent in /www/htdocs/w0114ce0/www/app/code/local/Mxsxs2/MyWidgets/controllers/IndexController.php, line 62
```

Exapmle code:

```
  public function indexAction(){
      echo("some text");  
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use `$this->getResponse()->setBody('your echo')`;